# How to simulate a long mouse left click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a little jquery script that help me doing some stuff when I'm not at my computer. Something like a bot.

This bot must perform some left-click on specific X,Y points of a page.

I use this code and works perfectly:
document.elementFromPoint(X, Y).click();

But I also need to do a long click on another point of the page.
I need to simulate this:
Press left click at (x,y) ... Wait 3 seconds ... Release left click.

Is there a way to do something like that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using pure JavaScript, this might not be possible. At least not for all circumstances.

However, if the element you're targeting is using `mousedown` and `mouseup` to detect this "long mouse click", then you could possibly trigger them directly:

```
document.elementFromPoint(X, Y).mousedown();

setTimeout(() => document.elementFromPoint(X, Y).mouseup(), 3000);
```

Like I said, won't work in all circumstances, since you aren't actually controlling the mouse itself, but should let you simulate it in some.

Answer (score 0):

Put a timeout listener between `mousedown` and `mouseup`

Not the *best* code, but you could do something like this:

```
function listenForLongClick (domElement, timeout = 3000) {
    let mouseDownStarted = false;
    let timeoutCheck = null;
    domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        mouseDownStarted = true;

        timeoutCheck = setTimeout(() => mouseDownStarted = false, timeout);
    }, false);
    domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutCheck);

        if (mouseDownStarted) { console.log('within the 3 seconds'); }

        mouseDownStarted = false;
    }, false);
}
```